# Sitecore Intranet Portal How to know if a user has accessed/(Viewed) an Item or not

Tags: c#, sitecore, portal, sitecore7.2, sitecore-intranet-portal

I have a page Item called news section. In this page the users can see the list of all the news, with News heading in bold.

Now what I want to do is to make the heading normal(non bold) for those users who have read the news.

For this I am thinking in sitecore to make a folder with every news Item and in that folder an item for every user with a checkBox field "Is read" in it.

But I am not sure how I can track the user has viewed/accessed an item or not. 
Should I use cookies? Or there is some out of the box functionality available in Sitecore to check if the user has accessed an item or not. ?

Answer (score 0):

That approach seems the wrong way round to me. I think you should focus on "the pages this person has viewed", not "the people who have viewed this page".

Since you're using Sitecore 7.2 (so don't have the xDB available), you could store the ID's of the News item's they have viewed. In my opinion, the best place to update the profile is in a `HttpRequestBegin` pipeline processor.

When a user lands on the page you just check their profile to see if the GUID of the current page is in their list.

You'll need to create a custom user profile, which is quite simple. See Section 3.5 of the Security API cookbook: https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/security_api_cookbook_a4.pdf

I think this approach is neater, becuase you don't have to create folders and special items for each person who views a page.

By the way, I'm assuming that your system will have manageable number of users and news pages. I doubt this would scale very well.